# "Index was outside the bounds of an array" for GameObject array initialize

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

does anyone know why this Is giving an error about the index being out of bounds for the gameobject arrays?

```
public GameObject[] Prefab;
public GameObject[] CopyPrefab;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    CopyPrefab[i] = Instantiate(Prefab[i]) as GameObject;
}
```

error: `IndexOutOfRangeExCeption: Index was outside the bounds of the array.`

I tried `CopyPrefab[i-1] = Instantiate(Prefab[i-1]) as GameObject;` and `CopyPrefab[i] = Instantiate(Prefab[0]) as GameObject;` . i don't get what i am doing wrong please

Comment: What is the value of `CopyPrefab.Length`? `Prefab.Length`? _Both when the exception occurs._

Answer (score 3):

How do you know the exact number of objects in your GameObject[]? Do not hardcode your loop end condition to i < 10. Instead you should either loop using a foreach-loop or use Array's Length property.

[Looping in C#](https://www.programiz.com/csharp-programming/foreach-loop)

Answer (score 0):

```
public GameObject[] Prefab;
public GameObject[] CopyPrefab;
CopyPrefab = new GameObject[Prefab.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < Prefab.Length; i++)
{
    CopyPrefab[i] = Instantiate(Prefab[i]) as GameObject;
}
```

First , make sure two array length is same , if CopyPrefab.Length = 10 ,
you just can use CopyPrefab[0...9] , Can't use CopyPrefab[-1] or CopyPrefab[10] ... "It Out of Range"